# How to generate repetitive bit pattern (strings) & export into text file?

Tags: c#, string, text-files

I'm trying to generate a bit pattern(repetitive strings) and export into a text file,

**Here's my code:**

```
string pattern_01010101 = "";
        
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     pattern_01010101 += "0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,";
}

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\BField_pattern_01010101.txt", pattern_01010101);
```

**Result:**

[image]

---

Now if I change the loop value to "***20***",

```
string pattern_01010101 = "";
        
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
     pattern_01010101 += "0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,";
}

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\BField_pattern_01010101.txt", pattern_01010101);
```

**Result:**

I get this funny little rectangle boxes,

[image]

could somebody please suggest me, what am I doing wrong here??

Many thanks for your time..:)

Comment: I just tested your code in here, and the problem indeed seems to be related to Microsoft Notepad and not with your code! If you open the file in other editor (I used Notepad++), you can see that the content is right in there...

Comment: @ Luiz, Clever, Yes You're right, I didn't think of it...:)

Comment: BTW, you can create the pattern easily by this code: `pattern = string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(0,20).Select(i=>(i&1)==0?"1":"0"));`

Comment: Apparently Notepad has some known issues with encoding (the comments mention weird squares as well): http://weblogs.asp.net/cumpsd/archive/2004/02/27/81098.aspx

Comment: @KingKing I would simplify to `string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(0, 160).Select(i => i % 2))`. You have swapped `0` and `1`, if that is desired, start the range from an odd number, as in `string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(1, 160).Select(i => i % 2))`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen good point, again I missed out the Join overload accepting `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: If you add `Environment.NewLine` (a.k.a. `"\r\n"`) to the end of the string, my version of Notepad will again interprete this as UTF-8 or ANSI (ASCII), rather than UTF-16 LE. You might also add a single space character (if the number of bytes is an odd number, it is hard to maintain the UTF-16 interpretation). These work-arounds can be useful if the Byte-Order-Mark is not wanted (perhaps because the file is going to be read by something which doesn't like BOM).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect there is some problem with the default `Encoding` used by `File.WriteAllText` method.

Try passing encoding you need explicitly and that works fine. for instance `Encoding.UTF8`.

```
File.WriteAllText(@"BField_pattern_01010101.txt", pattern_01010101, Encoding.UTF8);
```

I've investigated that `WriteAllText` also uses "UTF8Encoding" by default. but the only difference is with arguments passed in contructor. Encoding.UTF8 uses `new UTF8Encoding(true, false);` where as WriteAllText method uses `new UTF8Encoding(false, true);`

As noted in comments [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is the one causing trouble, Thanks @BjörnRoberg. First parameter of "UTF8Encoding constructor" defines whether to emit BOM or not.

Comment: It's because, by default, this method writes the file without a BOM, but the overload with the Encoding param writes with a BOM if needed.

Comment: @BjörnRoberg What is that BOM.. I can't get that. I just saw fields named as BOM in reflector

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (or BOM) tells programs what order the bytes are in a file, so they can parse them accordingly. Notepad++ seems to have some sort of autodetect-feature, whereas Notepad probably doesn't.

Comment: It is correct that `WriteAllText` by default uses UTF-8 without byte-order-mark, but that should be no problem when the text is all ASCII. Because with the "codepage" of the asker (he is in Britain as per his profile) a pure ASCII file should open fine with no byte-order-mark. Western European codepages are all supersets of ASCII. I know of __no__ (single-octet) codepages where the chars `'0'`, `','` and `'1'` are not in the same codepoint as they are in ASCII. Also it works with `10` in the loop, but not with `20`. So ___why___ is Notepad like that?!

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Have you referred to the link [Bush hid the facts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts) ? It appears the bug with notepad.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You are right. The other answers give the correct explanation. This means that some ASCII files will be interpreted as UTF-16 with no byte-order-mark by Notepad. There is no bug in the code written by San'. Just don't use Notepad.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a case of [Bush hid the facts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts). So it's not a bug in your app, it's a bug in notepad. When you write your file, specify the encoding explicitly (UTF-8 or Unicode or something with a byte order mark) to work around it. (By default File.WriteAllText uses UTF-8 without a BOM, so notepad has to guess the encoding, and the guesswork sometimes fails, apparently.)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not in your application.  In fact, if you open Notepad directly, enter `0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,` 20 times, save the file (ANSI encoding), and re-open the file, you will see the same behavior.

By default, the text file will be written in UTF-8 encoding without a Byte Order Mark (BOM).  When Notepad opens the file, it first must detect the proper encoding (e.g., Unicode or UTF8) based on only the contents of the text file.  This is done based on statistical analysis, using the [`IsTextUnicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318672%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.  The API notes that:

> The IS_TEXT_UNICODE_STATISTICS and IS_TEXT_UNICODE_REVERSE_STATISTICS tests use statistical analysis. These tests are not foolproof. The statistical tests assume certain amounts of variation between low and high bytes in a string, and some ASCII strings can slip through.

In the example of `0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1` repeated 20 times, the `IsTextUnicode` function incorrectly indicated the text was Unicode-encoded rather than UTF-8 encoded.  (This type false positive is perhaps most infamously present in [this bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts).)

As evidence, the following :

```
[DllImport("Advapi32", SetLastError = false)]
static extern bool IsTextUnicode(byte[] buf, int len, ref int opt);

...
int iter = 20;
string test = string test = String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,", iter));
var bytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test);
int opt = 0x20; // IS_TEXT_UNICODE_STATISTICS;
Console.WriteLine(IsTextUnicode(bytes, bytes.Length, ref opt));
```

If `iter > 10` (e.g., for more than 10 repetitions), the encoding will be interpreted, incorrectly, as Unicode.

Comment: Interestingly, when `0` (one octet `0x30`) followed by `,` (`0x2C`) is interpreted as a little-endian 16-bit word, we get `0x2C30`, which corresponds to `U+2C30`. Similarly `1` followed by `,` becomes `U+2C31`. So what Notepad really interpretes is `ⰰⰱⰰⰱⰰⰱ ...` which is like `ababab ...` in [Glagolitic script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glagolitic_alphabet). Beauty.

Comment: If you open the file from inside Notpad, you can specify the encoding in the _Open_ dialog. If you open from the command line, you can use `/A` to enforce ANSI (which will be good enough in this case), as in: `notepad.exe /A C:\BField_pattern_01010101.txt`.